# Cannot infer on Movidius (NCS2) using OpenVINO Workbench through Docker: Drivers setup failed?

Tags: docker, openvino, movidius

I am trying to run some inferences using the OpenVINO Workbench Docker image  https://hub.docker.com/r/openvino/workbench . Everything works well using my CPU as targeted device (Configuration -> Select Environment). But I get the following error when I select my Intel Movidius Myriad X VPU (a Neural Compute Stick  2):

"Cannot infer this model on Intel(R) Movidius(TM) Neural Compute Stick 2 (NCS 2). Possible causes: Drivers setup failed. Update the drivers or run inference on a CPU." (cf attached screenshot).

I did not change the start_workbench.sh script. Here are my execution params:

./start_workbench.sh -IMAGE_NAME openvino/workbench -TAG latest -ENABLE_MYRIAD -DETACHED -ASSETS_DIR /hdd-raid0/openvino_workbench

However, I can play with the NCS2 using the classification or cross check commands provided by https://hub.docker.com/r/openvino/ubuntu18_dev.

Any idea ?
Thxxxx!
[image: openvino dl workbench error screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can use a Docker* Image for Intel® Vision Accelerator Design with Intel® Movidius™ VPUs: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_docker_linux.html

Kindly navigate to the specific topic. You will found that there are a few additional steps to be done before NCS2 can be used with Docker.